# maven try to download localy exist jars

Tags: maven-2, netbeans

I download a jar  to my local reposotory but every times i compile netbeans try to download it why can be this happen i try to change dependecy scope but i couldnt figure out a solution.This is my dependency  i also try provided ,runtime... 
        
            jregex
            jregex
            1.2_01
            compile

Netbeans output as below and i use netbeans suggested maven command to store manualy downloaded jregex jar to my local repository and i also have other dependend jars instaled and stored my local repository  .

[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 3 resources
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2//jregex/jregex/1.2_01/jregex-1.2_01.pom
Unable to find resource 'jregex:jregex:pom:1.2_01' in repository repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/)
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2//jregex/jregex/1.2_01/jregex-1.2_01.pom
Unable to find resource 'jregex:jregex:pom:1.2_01' in repository java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jregex/jregex/1.2_01/jregex-1.2_01.pom
Unable to find resource 'jregex:jregex:pom:1.2_01' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` to the directory containing your `jregex-1.2_01.jar` file and run the following:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jregex -DartifactId=jregex -Dversion=1.2_01 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=jregex-1.2_01.jar
```

That will install the jar in your local repository as indicated by the dependency you wrote, which is (if I understood correctly):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jregex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jregex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_01</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you want to get rid of the warning, you can also add

```
 <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                 <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         // ...
     </plugins>
     // ...
</build>
```

**update**: check that the POM itself ([`jregex-1.2_01.pom`](https://maven.atlassian.com/maven1/maven2/jregex/jregex/1.2_01/jregex-1.2_01.pom)) is really on your local repository. Maybe this is obvious and you already did it but I'm out of ideas :) For some reason it could be that the jar is found there, but the pom is not. If this is not the case, you have some kind of mismatch between the local repository when maven runs and when you install the jar from console, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: my problem is i allready do this and install missing jar to my local repository and my project successfully compile but problem is it still try to download .

Comment: yes problem jregex-1.2_01.jar in my local repositoy but its pom not,and i dont know why maven need that pom.

Comment: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<your_group_name>  \
-DartifactId=<your_artifact_name>  \
-Dversion=<snapshot>  \
-Dfile=<path_to_your_jar_file>  \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-DgeneratePom=true

Answer (score 0):

- Your dependency may be in a wrong directory
- Your "settings.xml" file may point to a local path where the dependency doesn't exist.

You should post an extract from your pom.xml, settings.xml and the path to the dependency if you want further explanations...

Answer (score 0):

or your dependency doesn't have a pom file in the remote repository and maven re-attempts to download it.

please try with recently released nb 7.0, it has the uptodate maven 3.x binaries embedded.